# How can this irrational integral be solved?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm interested in solving the following indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{u'(x)}{\sqrt{a+b\cdot u(x)^2+c\cdot u(x)^4}}dx$$

Where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given constants. Could it be solved explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b\cdot y^2+c\cdot y^4}}\,dy$  or $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^4 - k^2}}\,dz$ ?

Comment: If you are fine with elliptic integrals, sure.

Comment: Maybe using a Jacobi elliptic function? I'm not very used with that...